# In SourceTree is it possible to use both GitHub and Bitbucket with one instance?

Tags: github, version-control, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

SourceTree appears to be a decent GUI frontend to both Git and Hg and I'd like to use it as my client for both Bitbucket and Github.

However, on initial setup it offers only to add one of them and later on in the settings one can only edit the existing entries but not add new ones.

Is there a way to use SourceTree against both Github and Bitbucket at the same time?

I am using SourceTree 1.6.12.0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I use for both. I think I used github first. Then later I added a new repo, selected clone from url and gave it a bitbucket url. Works fine.

Comment: how do you do it, though?

Comment: It's in the answer. Add new repo. Clone from url. Enter bitbucket url.